# Getting value of multiple <select> that has chosen jquery plugin

Tags: jquery-chosen

I have a `<select mutiple>` which has the [chosen function](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) attached to it, turning it into something like a tag selector.

I am then sending its multiple values via an ajax call.

I am currently using this:

```
var x_CoPayers = $("#x_CoPayersChargeEdit").val();
```

but when I view the parameters that are sent by ajax, they look like this:

```
x_CoPayers[] = 9813
x_CoPayers[] = 9786
```

Of course that doesn't work for me, because the parameter i am looking for on the other side is called `x_CoPayers`.

I would like them each to be called `x_CoPayers`, or alternatively, like this: `x_CoPayers= 9813,9786`.

I have also tried this, without result:

```
   var  x_CoPayers = $("#x_CoPayersChargeEdit").chosen().val();
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer ;)

add `join(',')`  at the end, so:

```
$("#x_CoPayersChargeEdit").val().join(',');
```